# Log4j2 Metrics with Micrometer

Tags: java, log4j2, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am trying to get log events metrics using Log4j2 & Micrometer. My setup -> Spring Boot application running on Azure with Azure monitoring javaagent which internally creates a [AzureMonitorMeterRegistry](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/implementations/micrometer-registry-azure-monitor/src/main/java/io/micrometer/azuremonitor/AzureMonitorMeterRegistry.java).

**Problem :-**

It seems while using the async appender, metric count is less than expected. Refer :-

[image] (It's a StepCounter that's why you do no see ever increasing trend of the counter.)

Once I switched to sync logger, I started getting correct numbers.

How can I get correct metrics count while using async appender ? The relevant code is present in [Log4j2Metrics](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/logging/Log4j2Metrics.java) - a MeterBinder implementation. In here, decision is made whether to increment the counter using :-

```
@Override
public Result filter(LogEvent event) {

    if (!isAsyncLogger || isAsyncLoggerAndEndOfBatch(event)) {
      // increments by 1
      incrementCounter(event); // shouldn't this be incremented by "batch size" in case of async logger ?
    }

    return Result.NEUTRAL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are experiencing is due to the unsolved [micrometer-metrics/micrometer#2176](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/2176) issue.

Since filters are usually side-effect free, the current (2.20.0) version of Log4j2 Core calls the filter 3 times for async loggers. Currently Micrometer works around this issue by counting the number of event **batches** instead of single events. When the system is idle there is usually a single event per batch, but that changes when the system is under load.

I added [apache/logging-log4j2#1550](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1550) to keep track of this issue.

**Edit**: The Log4j2 bug was fixed in version 2.21.0 and Micrometer corrected their filter in [micrometer-metrics/micrometer#4253](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/pull/4253), which is scheduled to be released in version 1.12.0.

Comment: @KumarSambhav: remark that only async **loggers** are affected by the issue above (which are specific to Log4j2 Core). Async **appenders** are not affected.